# How to configure Intellij Idea 12 Community Edition to work with JSF 2.x?

Tags: jsf-2, intellij-idea

I have searched in Internet, but I only found information about Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as stated in Intellij Idea's [comparision matrix](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) Java EE frameworks, such as Servlets, JSP, JSF, Web Services, CDI, Bean Validation, Web Beans, etc. are supported only in Ultimate Edition.

So the answer is JSF is not supported. In order to use CE for this technology you would have to configure everything on your own. I would suggest you to use other IDE, like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: Thank you! I need to look for another options. Netbeans is a good idea.

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, it is appreciated to accept it:)